# Post Request C# not working - 401 (Bad Request)

Tags: c#, twilio, http-post, twilio-api

I am trying to get response from the Twilio API through a POST request:

[https://analytics.ytica.com/gdc/app/projects/{{WorkSpaceID}}/execute/raw](https://analytics.ytica.com/gdc/app/projects/%7B%7BWorkSpaceID%7D%7D/execute/raw)

And I am passing token in the API as a header generated from https://analytics.ytica.com/gdc/account/token.

I am doing the API call, using the following lines of code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://analytics.ytica.com/gdc/app/projects/{{WorkspaceID}}/execute/raw");
client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "GDCAuthTT="+token);
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n    \"report_req\": {\r\n    \"report\": \"/gdc/md/{{WorkspaceID}}/obj/{{Report}}\"\r\n  }\r\n}",  ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

After executing this is am getting the following error as a JSON response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Authorization Required",
        "description": "This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required",
        "links": {
            "documentation": "https://help.gooddata.com/display/developer/API+Reference#/reference/authentication/log-in"
        }
    }
}
```

Please advise me how to solve the error.

Comment: did you test it with other tools like postman , fiddle ... ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with postman and it's working there

Comment: Did you read webpage in json response?

Comment: I am not sure, can you please advise what can I try